# Matematica If Statement

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica i am using this following code:

```
If[ x [[1]] <= 4 && x [[2]] <= 4, "True","False"]
True
```

This is where i get confused:

```
If[ True, count=count + 1, count=count]
```

I do not no how to access the answer from the line before code

Comment: to actually use the result later in your code assign it a symbol, ie. result=If[ ... ];  (...)   If[result, ... ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't just

```
If[ x [[1]] <= 4 && x [[2]] <= 4, count++]
```

?

Comment: only my second week using mathematica but thanks for the idea

Answer (score 3):

In addition to belisarius' answer you may consider:

```
count += Boole[x[[1]] <= 4 && x[[2]] <= 4]
```

Also, you said: "I do not no how to access the answer from the line before code."

You could use `%`:

```
If[ x [[1]] <= 4 && x [[2]] <= 4, True, False];

If[%, count=count + 1, count=count]
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally you could just fit one piece of code inside the other:

```
If[ 
   If[ x [[1]] <= 4 && x [[2]] <= 4, True, False],
   count=count + 1, count=count
]
```

Note that the strings `"True"` and `"False"` have been replaced with their logical values `True` and `False`